# How to insert a block of equation at the right of the line

Tags: math-mode

I want to write an equation like
`X \sim N(\mu, \sigma^2)` 
at the center of the line, and `\mu \in \mathbb{R}, \sigma^2 \in \mathbb{R}^2` at the right, how can I do?

Comment: Welcome to TeX. SE! Of course you can.  What you try sp far? Where you stuck?

Comment: Any news? You got two answers, does any of them helpful?

Answer (score 2):

Here are some options:

1. A typical centered equation with a `\qquad` space between the equation and the condition.
2. A centered equation with an off-centered condition.
3. A centered equation and right-aligned condition.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools,amsfonts}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1][1-2]
\[
  X \sim N(\mu, \sigma^2) \qquad \mu \in \mathbb{R}, \sigma^2 \in \mathbb{R}^2
\]
\lipsum[1][3-4]

\lipsum[1][1-2]
\[
  X \sim N(\mu, \sigma^2) \mathrlap{\qquad \mu \in \mathbb{R}, \sigma^2 \in \mathbb{R}^2}
\]
\lipsum[1][3-4]

\lipsum[1][1-2]
\[
  \makebox[\linewidth]{$\displaystyle X \sim N(\mu, \sigma^2)$}
  \makebox[0pt][r]{$\mu \in \mathbb{R}, \sigma^2 \in \mathbb{R}^2$}
\]
\lipsum[1][3-4]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not entirely clear, so I guess, that you may looking for something like this:

[image]

Do I'm right?

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[thick]    (0,0) -- node[fill=white] {$X \sim N(\mu, \sigma^2)$}
                (5,0)   node[fill=white, right] {$\mu \in \mathbb{R}, \sigma^2 \in \mathbb{R}^2$};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps using the `\tag*{}` in a display math mode would be helpful. For you case I think the following would suffice.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsfonts}

\begin{document}

  Some text.
  \[X \sim N(\mu, \sigma^2) \tag*{$\mu \in \mathbb{R}, \sigma^2 \in \mathbb{R}^2$}\]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this, perhaps?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{flalign*}
        && X &\sim N(\mu, \sigma^2) & \mu \in \mathbb{R}, \sigma^2 \in \mathbb{R}^2
\end{flalign*}
\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

Explanation: the `flalign` environment from `amsmath` prints like an `align`, but each pair that forms a column in the `align` are spread out as far as possible. So you can place an empty first column, your centered stuff in the second column, and your right-aligned stuff on the third column.

If you want the middle column to be truly centered, you may want to put in a `\phantom{\mu\in \mathbb{R}, \sigma^2 \in \mathbb{R}^2}` as your first column to create some space.